# How to enable a disabled User Account on a MacBook Pro running OS X El Captain?

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, macos, user-account

I disabled a User Account in the *System Preferences > Users & Groups > Right-click on a User > Advanced Options... > Login shell:* using: `/bin/false`

Now the disabled account is visible in the login window but is gone under System Preferences.  I used `sudo chsh <username> /bin/bash` and `sudo chpass -s /bin/bash <username>` in *Terminal* and it didn’t bring it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the proper *disable* Login Shell value is: */usr/bin/false* instead of */bin/false*. So I don't know if your */bin/false* is just a typo or not.

Even using the false UserShell I haven't been able to reproduce your problem though.

You can try the following: open Terminal and enter

```
dscl . read /Users/user_name
```

to check if the user *user_name* is still there.

Then check *UserShell*:

```
dscl . read /Users/user_name UserShell
```

To modify *UserShell* use:

```
sudo dscl . change /Users/user_name UserShell /bin/false /bin/bash
```

Depending on the value found previously you may have to use /usr/bin/false instead of /bin/false as shell which should be replaced.

Then recheck *UserShell*:

```
dscl . read /Users/user_name UserShell
```

which should yield:

> UserShell: /bin/bash

Exit Terminal and open System Preferences. The proper UserShell value should make the lost user visible again in the System Preferences > Users & Groups.